# Getting data from Firebase in Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Hi so I'm moving my app from a MySQL database to Firebase, but I'm having trouble getting the connection between my c# code and firebase set up.

So I have a Firestore database that looks like this:

[Firebase database with "Persons" collection containing one record with an auto-generated Id. This record contains Admin (set to true) and Fullname (set to PJ)][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFF9A.png

I have this code:

```
        public static async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
          {
              Fullname = item.Object.Fullname,
              Admin = item.Object.Admin
          }).ToList();
    }
```

But when I try to execute the function i get this error message:

```
Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: Exception occured while processing the 
request.
Url: https://moveeasy-72594.firebaseio.com/Persons/.json
Request Data: 
Response: {
  "error" : "404 Not Found"
}
```

I've set my rules to this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: The security rules you've included are for Cloud Storage, but your code is accessing the Firebase Realtime Database. While both products are part of Firebase, they have nothing to do with each other aside from that and the API and security rules for one don't affect the other.

Comment: I set it back to the default, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you may be using the wrong URL to access your database. If you created the database to be in Western Europe, its URL is one of these:

- https://moveeasy-72594.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Persons.json
- https://moveeasy-72594-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Persons.json

Try initializing Firebase with these URLs and see if that works for you.

Comment: is that not for a realtime database? I'm looking to use a firestore databse. Sorry if that doesnt make sense I'm still getting my head around it

Comment: The error message is explicitly coming from Realtime Database. This code also looks like RTDB: `firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()`

Comment: I've put the firebasedatabase.app into the xamarin/firebase sample solution i have and it inserted some data sucessfully. I'll have to do some reading on the difference between firestore/realtime but I'm happy that ive got something working at least. Thanks for you help!